# Web Application: View Layer PHP Vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

I'm developing a web application using PHP. I am creating a custom MVC framework. I have a few large forms which have to be loaded with data. I have to decide whether I use Javascript code to render this data or PHP like below. I know the syntax, I just want to know the pros and cons for each alternative.

```
function renderFormData(data){
  $("#name").val(data.name);
}

<label class="normal" for="">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if(isset($data{'NAME1'})) echo $data{'NAME1'}?>" />
```

Comment: I generally only offload heavy load times to ajax, unless it makes more sense in the UI to have the interaction be ajax'd. So, think about what makes the most sense. Would I ajax in simple form data? Probably not.

Comment: _"I am creating a custom MVC framework."_ Is this for your own education, or for production use? If it's for production use, please strongly consider using an existing framework. Building your own adds a huge maintenance burden to your project, and you can't take advantage of existing communities or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on overall architecture. If yo have cached form template at the client side, you can just make request for data and render form at client side. In case you plan to request template and then data, then, I guess, go for server side rendering.